# request a image but nginx return 200 and a blank response header

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails

When browser(Windows IE8,9 and Windows Chrome(20) and Mac Chrome(20)) request a set of images, some image requests return 304 and display correctly, but others return 200OK and a blank response header, it will display a random image from page.

```
Request URL:
http://example.com/statics/images/b_9215b819d9fc2500feb1ec8e12d41f98.jpg

Request Method:
GET

Status Code:
200 OK

Request Headersview source

Accept:
*/*

Accept-Charset:
GBK,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

Accept-Encoding:
gzip,deflate,sdch

Accept-Language:
zh-CN,zh;q=0.8

Connection:
keep-alive

Cookie:
remember_user_token=BAhbB1sGaQLoHkkiIiQyYSQxMCRNRjE5UWMydVBUajBYcExHMy93dWdPBjoGRVQ%3D--5d1166be5cabacc37c4b8d246105f4cb9bd35b7b; CNZZDATA3722561=cnzz_eid=41795721-1343110343-&ntime=1343360172&cnzz_a=16&retime=1343360179980&sin=none&ltime=1343360179980&rtime=3; _sparrow_session=f9afb2f3c4f87635eca43fc1a94abc85

Host:
example.com

If-Modified-Since:
Fri, 20 Jul 2012 21:06:01 GMT

If-None-Match:
"b65cefa739e8ac4fb62bc00304962d3c"

Referer:
http://example.com/guide

User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11 QIHU 360EE
Response Headersview source

x-content-type-options:
nosniff
```

Help me~ Thank you.

Comment: What is "blank response header"?

Comment: Is there any logs in nginx logs or your RoR app log? And try use `curl -v http://example.com/statics/images/b_9215b819d9fc2500feb1ec8e12d41f98.jpg` and post the result here.

Comment: Please send nginx config, maybe nginx access/error log, without these your question is meaningless.